# sql query with unixtime

Tags: mysql, sql, phpmyadmin, unix-timestamp

I am trying to select everything from my table with today's date. But I found that that date column is in unix time stamp. So, how do I select everything with today's date? or for example only yesterday's ? If it was normal date instead of unix time it would be easy, but... here is what I have put for my query so far..

```
$ann_renewal_query = "SELECT * FROM annual_renewal WHERE due_date  '%$today%' order BY due_date ASC";
```

Comment: I am using phpmyadmin

Comment: That is not a database.  Presumably, you are using MySQL.

Comment: yes, sorry, i am using mysql

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You just need to convert the values to the unix timestamp version.  The best way is to convert the current time to Unix timestamp:

```
where due_date >= UNIX_TIMESTAMP(curdate()) and
      due_date < UNIX_TIMESTAMP(date_add(curdate(), interval 1 day)
```

This version of the query allows it to take advantage of an index on `due_date`.